# Error generating pdf from latex file in django in production

Tags: python, django, pdf, latex, temp

I developed a system to generate a pdf through a latex file and deployed it to a Windows server using Microsoft SII, on my local machine it generates the pdf normally, but in production it generates the following error:

Command 'cd "C:\Windows\TEMP\tmpzrdfals9" && pdflatex -interaction=batchmode  texput.tex' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Here's the code of the view:

```
def verFormularioDesconto(request,id):
    with connections['integracaoSiem'].cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "SELECT VALIDA_DIREITO_DESCONTO_FUNC(%(id)s,'APROVACAO'),\
              VALIDA_DIREITO_DESCONTO_FUNC(%(id)s,'CRM_RT') ,\
              VALIDA_DIREITO_DESCONTO_FUNC(%(id)s,'NM_RT'), \
              VALIDA_DIREITO_DESCONTO_FUNC(%(id)s,'NU_REGISTRO_EMPRESA'),\
              VALIDA_DIREITO_DESCONTO_FUNC(%(id)s,'RAZAO_SOCIAL'),\
              VALIDA_DIREITO_DESCONTO_FUNC(%(id)s,'CNPJ'), \
              VALIDA_DIREITO_DESCONTO_FUNC(%(id)s,'ID_SOLICITACAO'), \
              VALIDA_DIREITO_DESCONTO_FUNC(%(id)s,'PRAZO') \
              FROM DUAL"
        valores = {'id':id}
        cursor.execute(sql,valores)
        resultado = cursor.fetchall()
        

    context = {
        "date": datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        "CRM_RT": resultado[0][1],
        "NM_RT": resultado[0][2],
        "NU_REGISTRO_EMPRESA": resultado[0][3],
        "RAZAO_SOCIAL": resultado[0][4],
        "CNPJ": resultado[0][5],
        "ID_SOLICITACAO": str(resultado[0][6].zfill(5)),

    }
    if resultado[0][0] =='A' and resultado[0][7] == 'S':
        return render_to_pdf(request, "latex/formularioDesconto.tex", context,filename='Requerimento_de_desconto.pdf')
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Página não encontrada</h1>')
```

latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{ {{date}} }
\rhead{ Nº Solicitação: {{ID_SOLICITACAO}}  }

\cfoot{ \thepage}


\marginsize{30mm}{30mm}{20mm}{20mm}




\date{}

\begin{document}

\section*{REQUERIMENTO DE DESCONTO DE 80\% NA ANUIDADE PESSOA JURÍDICA 2021}

%\maketitle 

Número de registro da EMPRESA no CRMMG: {{NU_REGISTRO_EMPRESA}}
\\
Número de inscrição no CNPJ: {{CNPJ}}
\\
Razão Social: {{RAZAO_SOCIAL}}

\vspace{1em}
Eu, {{NM_RT}}, CRMMG n.º {{CRM_RT}}, Responsável
Técnico do estabelecimento acima identificado, venho REQUERER junto ao Conselho Regional de
Medicina do Estado de Minas Gerais, desconto de 80\% sobre o valor da anuidade relativa ao
exercício de 2020, atribuída à empresa supra, conforme disposto pelo artigo 18 da resolução CFM
nº 2.231, de 04 de Julho de 2019[1]. DECLARO que a Pessoa Jurídica em questão é composta por
no máximo dois sócios, sendo obrigatoriamente um deles médico, possui capital social inferior a
R\$ 50.000,00 (cinquenta mil reais), é constituída exclusivamente para execução de consultas
médicas, sem a realização de exames complementares para diagnósticos, feitos em seu próprio
consultório e que não mantém contratação de serviços médicos a serem prestados por terceiros,
bem como está em situação financeira e cadastral regular perante o CRMMG. Nestes termos, pede deferimento.
\\
\\
Belo Horizonte, MG - {{date}}


\vspace{2em}
\begin{center}
\line(1,0){15 cm}

\textbf{ASSINATURA COM IDENTIFICAÇÃO (CARIMBO OU NOME E Nº DE CRMMG) DO RESPONSÁVEL TÉCNICO}

\end{center}

\vspace{1em}

\begin{flushleft}
E-mail:\line(1,0){13,85 cm}
\vspace{1em}
\textbf{Dados Bancários}
\vspace{1em}

Tipo de conta: [ ] Pessoa Jurídica, [ ] Pessoa Física (Responsável Técnico); 
\vspace{1em}

CPF do titular:\line(1,0){12,6 cm}

Banco:\line(1,0){13,96 cm}

Agência:\line(1,0){13,7 cm}

Conta Corrente:\line(1,0){12,5 cm}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Some settings in settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'sgc.apps.SgcConfig',
    'emailMarketing.apps.EmailmarketingConfig',
    'ckeditor',
    'bootstrapform',
    'django_filters',
    'localflavor',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'pessoa.apps.PessoaConfig',
    'funcionario.apps.FuncionarioConfig',
    'global_permissions',
    'integracaoSiem.apps.IntegracaosiemConfig',
    'direitoDesconto.apps.DireitodescontoConfig',
    'django_tex',
    'sgdoc.apps.SgdocConfig',
]
LATEX_INTERPRETER = 'pdflatex'
TEMPLATES = [    
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    #configuração template LateX
    {
        "NAME": "tex",
        "BACKEND": "django_tex.engine.TeXEngine",
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "custom_templates")],
    },
]
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'temp')
```

I've already tried deploying using Apache and it generates the same error. Has anyone been through this or know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: From the tex perspective the problem is that you must not use `_` in normal text (that's only for math), so instead of `NU_REGISTRO_EMPRESA` it should be `NU\_REGISTRO\_EMPRESA` (or written in verbatim). Full file: https://pastebin.com/Fy0AW30G

Comment: Hi! 
In the case of these words who have "_", and that they are variables that django replaces with text

Comment: I tried the way you said, but the error persists. Thank you for your willingness